# JQuery Mobile - ASP.NET MVC - Stylesheet is never executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I use a ASP.NET MVC 4 project with JQuery, JQuery Mobile, etc.

This is my popup dialog that is in the same page of my main page.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="a">
   <div data-role="header">
      <p id="headerMessage">Recherche de recettes</p>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content">
      @using(Html.BeginForm("GetRecipes","Recipes",FormMethod.Post)){
        <input id="classicSearchInput" name="classicSearchInput" type="text" />
        <div id="buttonDialog">
           <button id="okBtn" data-role="button" data-ajax="false" data-inline="true" data-rel="back"  data-theme="c">OK</button>
           <a id="cancelDialogBtn" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      }
   </div>

</div>
```

In my popup, when I click on the "OK" button, it's going well to the "GetRecipes" controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetRecipes() {
    String recipe = HttpContext.Request.Form["classicSearchInput"];

    try{
       var client = new FacebookClient((String)Session["accessToken"]);
    }
    catch (FacebookOAuthException foe){
       Session["accessToken"] = "";

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
       Session["accessToken"] = "";

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }

    List<Recipe> recipeList = new List<Recipe>();

    using (Entities entitie = new Entities()) {
        String recipeSearched = recipe.Replace("é", "e").Replace("è", "e").Replace("ê", "e").Replace("à", "a").ToLower();

        recipeList = entitie.Recipes
                            .Include("Votings")
                            .Include("SocialNetworkClient")
                            .Where(a => 
                                   a.title.Replace("é", "e").Replace("è", "e").Replace("ê", "e").Replace("à", "a").ToLower()
                                    .Contains(recipeSearched))
                             .ToList();


         ViewBag.previousPage = "/Home";

         return View("~/Views/Recipes/Index.cshtml", recipeList);
    }

}
```

I've no problem with the controller. But when the controller returns the view 'Recipes', there is a problem. It executes well the lines with @Styles and @Scripts but it doesn't execute the different stylesheets(RecipeLandscape.css, RecipePortrait.css,...) and the javascript below. It executes just the following line and that's all :

```
@Html.Partial("_RecipeList", Model.ToList())
```

/Views/Recipes/Index.cshtml :

```
@model IEnumerable<ICookApp.Models.Recipe>
<html>
<head>
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
   @Scripts.Render("~/ScriptsJQuery")

   @Styles.Render("~/ratingStarStyle")
   @Scripts.Render("~/ratingStarScript")

  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/RecipesLandscape.css")" media="screen and (orientation:landscape)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/RecipesPortrait.css")" media="screen and (orientation:portrait)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/HeaderPortrait.css")"  media="screen and (orientation:portrait)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/HeaderLandscape.css")"  media="screen and (orientation:landscape)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/All.css" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[title='recipe']").each(function () {
            var val = parseInt($(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val());

            var t = $(this).children(".star").length;
        });

        $(".star").rating('readOnly', true);
    });
  </script>
  <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
     <div data-role="content">
        @Html.Partial("_RecipeList", Model.ToList())
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the strange print :

[image]

I would have to get this :

[image]
Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: When you say it doesn't execute the stylesheets, do you mean the rendered page doesn't contain those <link> tags at all, or just that the URL of the stylesheet isn't being fetched successfully?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: I don't have any errors but the "<link>" and "<script>" tags are never executed and so, I've a strange print. It's strange because the urls of the different stylesheets are correct.

Comment: Could you show the rendered html output please?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the rendered source.  I want to see exactly which parts of the html are missing/incorrect

Comment: The problem is the <link> stylesheet tags are never executed but when I call this page from another place from my application, it works